# Set html td width based on variable

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I currently have a p-table in my html which loops through a list of categories and creates the colspan based on how many categories there are:

```
            <ng-container *ngFor="let category of this.categoryList ">
              <th
                [attr.colspan]="category.columnNumber"
                style="white-space: normal; padding: 0.4;"
              >
                {{ category.name }}
              </th>
            </ng-container>
```

However, i am trying to make the style width attribute based off the colspan. So if the colspan is 2, the width would be 200px. If the colspan was 4, it would be 400px and so on.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ngClass`.

Define your classes:

```
w-200: {
  width: 200px;
}

w-400: {
  width: 400px;
}
// etc
```

Then in your template add `ngClass` and a configuration object.

```
<th [attr.colspan]="category.columnNumber" 
    style="white-space: normal; padding: 0.4;"
    [ngClass]="{w-200: category.columnNumber === 2, 'w-400': category.columnNumber === 4}">
      {{ category.name }}
</th>
```